# Integration of Flutter Flip_widget with PageView

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to integrate Flutter [flip_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flip_widget) with Flutter's `PageView.builder` widget.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;



const double _MinNumber = 0.008;
double _clampMin(double v) {
  if (v < _MinNumber && v > -_MinNumber) {
    if (v >= 0) {
      v = _MinNumber;
    } else {
      v = -_MinNumber;
    }
  }
  return v;
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  GlobalKey<FlipWidgetState> _flipKey = GlobalKey();

  Offset _oldPosition = Offset.zero;
  bool _visible = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = Size(256, 256);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Visibility(
              child: Container(
                width: size.width,
                height: size.height,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: FlipWidget(
                    key: _flipKey,
***// I want to add my PageView.builder here*** 
                    child: Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("hello"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onHorizontalDragStart: (details) {
                    _oldPosition = details.globalPosition;
                    _flipKey.currentState?.startFlip();
                  },
                  onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
                    Offset off = details.globalPosition - _oldPosition;
                    double tilt = 1 / _clampMin((-off.dy + 20) / 100);
                    double percent = math.max(0, -off.dx / size.width * 1.4);
                    percent = percent - percent / 2 * (1 - 1 / tilt);
                    _flipKey.currentState?.flip(percent, tilt);
                  },
                 
                ),
              ),
              visible: _visible,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to add my PageView.builder at the place on Text Widget Container.

So I tried and implemented but I am getting a new page without Flip animation.

So if Anyone can suggest me then it will be very useful for me.